# Why can't React test read the 'checked' property

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test if a React component renders recipes from an external API after the user types in a query, selects a checkbox option, and presses the search button. I am expecting a button with the text "Recipe" to render. When I run the test the following error is returned:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked').

```
let str = "";                                                                                                                
      29 |     for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {                                                                                     
    > 30 |       if (boxes[i].checked) {
         |                    ^
      31 |         str = str + boxes[i].value;
      32 |       }
      33 |     }
```

The test is getting stuck within the 'checkbox' function found within the SearchPage component (provided below):

```
import './SearchPage.css';
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import RecipeImgs from '../RecipeImgs/RecipeImgs.js';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function SearchPage() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState([]);
  const [hits, setHits] = useState([]);
  const [check, setCheck] = useState([]);
  const scrollResults = useRef(null);
  
  // error comes from the conditional statement below
  let checkbox = () => {
    let boxes = document.forms[0];
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i].checked) {
        str = str + boxes[i].value;
      }
    }
    setCheck(str);
  };

  const recipes = async () => {
    const url = `http://localhost:8000/food?q=${query}${check}`
    try {
      const request = await axios.request(url);
      if (request.data.hits === 0) {
        alert ('No results! Please try again.');
      }
      setHits(request.data.hits);
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert ('Oh no! Only 10 searches per minute please. Try again in 60 seconds.');
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  //when form is submitted
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    recipes();
    //scrolls down to results
    setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo({
      top: scrollResults.current.offsetTop,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })}, 500);
  }

  return (
    <div className='search-container'>
      <div className='nav-header'>
        <Link to = "/foodquest/"><div className="nav-logo"><img src={tomato} alt="tomato" /></div></Link>
        <nav className="nav">
          <ul>
            <li className="nav-home"><Link to="/foodquest/"><img src={home} alt="home icon" />Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/foodquest/search"><img src={bowl} alt="food icon" />Search</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/foodquest/random"><img src={random} alt="dice icon" />Random</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/foodquest/about"><img src={info} alt="info icon" />About</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className='search-input-container'>
        <h1>Recipe Search</h1>
        <form className='search-form' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <input className='search-field' type='text' placeholder='Enter ingredients' 
          value={query} onChange={(e)=> setQuery(e.target.value)}/>
          <div className='checkbox-container'>
            <div className='checkboxes'>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=dairy-free" onChange={checkbox}/>dairy-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=gluten-free" onChange={checkbox}/>gluten-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=peanut-free" onChange={checkbox}/>peanut-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=tree-nut-free" onChange={checkbox}/>tree-nut-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=wheat-free" onChange={checkbox}/>wheat-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=soy-free" onChange={checkbox}/>soy-free</label>
            </div>
            <div className='checkboxes'>
            <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=fish-free" onChange={checkbox}/>fish-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=shellfish-free" onChange={checkbox}/>shellfish-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=egg-free" onChange={checkbox}/>egg-free</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=vegan" onChange={checkbox}/>vegan</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=vegetarian" onChange={checkbox}/>vegetarian</label>
              <label className='check-option'><input type="checkbox" value="&health=paleo" onChange={checkbox}/>paleo</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type='submit' ref={scrollResults}>Get Recipe</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className='search-result-container'>
        {hits.map((index) => {
          return <RecipeImgs props={index} key={index.recipe.uri} />
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchPage;
```

SearchPage.test.js:

```
import SearchPage from "../SearchPage";
import {render, screen, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

test("render recipes from API response on SearchPage component", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()
  render(
    <Router>
      <SearchPage />
    </Router>
  ) 
  // target input, checkbox, and search button
  const query = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Enter ingredients') ;
  const check = screen.getByText('dairy-free');
  const button = screen.getByRole('button');
  // simulate typing 'apple' into input and clicking the 'dairy-free' checkbox
  await user.type(query, 'apple');
  await user.click(check);

  await user.click(button); 

  await waitFor(() =>  
    expect(screen.getAllByText('Recipe')[0]).toBeInTheDocument()
  )   
});
```

If I remove the code 'userEvent.click(check)', which checks the checkbox, it passes. The component works manually, but I can't get the test to work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `boxes` is not referring to a collection of input elements but the form itself. Also, not related to your problem, but `userEvent` returns a promise so you should await it.

Comment: @Terry: The checkbox function works manually as the desired state variable is properly updated onclick. What change would allow the function to work manually and not stump the test? Also, thank you for the userEvent correction.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that document.forms[0] contained elements, other than checkboxes, that have been throwing off the test. I assigned a 'check-input' class to the checkboxes and targeted them using querySelectorAll() and it worked.

```
    let checkbox = () => {
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check-input');
    let str = "";
    for (let box of boxes) {
      if (box.checked) {
        str += box.value;
      }
    }
    setCheck(str);
  };
```